# Google cloud platform TLS 1.0 update?

Tags: firebase, ssl, google-cloud-platform, tls1.2

We had a 3rd party security company review our site and they came back saying we should update to TLS 1.2 but im not sure how to do so on GCP. They also said we should update our SSL ciphers to more than 112 bits not sure how to do that either. If someone knows how to fix these or has links on how that would be amazing

Comment: Hi there! What HTTP server are you running (NGINX, Apache, etc). You see, these changes need to be done on your app and they are not related to GCP, unless you are using a GCP managed Load Balancer or a managed service like App Engine. Please add more information about your architecture and what GCP services you are using

Comment: For HTTP(S) Load Balancers apply a TLS Policy. Some Google services such as Cloud Run do not support TLS Policies. Your question has no details to know which services you are using.

Comment: From what i gather from our dev team we are using apache and PaaS on GCP.

Comment: If you are using Apache on Google Compute Engine and no load balancer, then you can configure TLS policy in Apache. However, an answer requires exact details. Simply saying **Apache and Paas** is not enough. Read this document on configuring Apache TLS security. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/ssl/ssl_howto.html

Comment: Could you please specify which services of GCP are using the TLS cipher suite? In order to provide a detailed answer to your issue we need more specific information.

Comment: Google Function, Firestore as the main plus some accesory services does this help make it more clear sorry for the lack of info

Answer (score 1):

According to the information that you provided, you're using Apache with Cloud Functions and Firestore, please correct me if I'm wrong.

From the Google side if you have a Google Cloud Load Balancer (GCLB) with Serverless NEGs (Cloud Run, GAE, or GCF custom domains) you can define a SSL security policy to restrict the [TLS versions](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/use-ssl-policies) and cipher suites used. I suggest you that before you configure your TLS version to check the [SSL policies overview](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-policies-concepts#defining_an_ssl_policy).

Otherwhise if you have another set up, I suggest you to check the [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/ssl/ssl_howto.html) that @John Hanley shared with you in the comments.

Comment: Would this also increase our SSL cipher strength? we have medium strength ciphers and id like to strength that as well. or is it a more complicated to the point i should open another thread

Comment: Acording to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-policies-concepts) you can specify a minimum TLS version and a profile. The profile selects a set of SSL features to enable in the load balancer.Additionally, it says that you can select a  fourth custom profile that lets you select SSL features individually.
So in summary you can increase your SSL cipher strenght.